# Can we ensemble multiple models using the same algorithm but with different features?

Tags: machine-learning

I am a beginner in machine learning and I wonder if I have any misinterpret or misunderstanding of the ensemble learning concept itself.

As far as I know, the more diverse or unrelated the model, the better the ensemble model will be. So,

1. It is generally better to use different algorithms to the models than all models trained using the same classifier.
2. Is there any reason to ensemble multiple models using the same algorithm?
3. Can I use the same classifier algorithm but differ in the features? To provide more context, what I am trying to classify is music genres, and I am thinking of utilizing MFCC, Mel-spectrogram, and spectral flux, where each feature is trained on different models. I think it still makes sense, no? The model diversity comes from the features used to train each model.
4. There are a lot of works to do here, starting from pre-processing the data, tuning the hyperparameters, extracting the previous 3 features, normalizing, and ensemble the models. Is it too much to do for a beginner for only around 5 months? Should I and how to narrowed down the focus?

Can you correct me if you find some misunderstandings on my statements? Or is there a better suggestion to your knowledge?
Your answer will be very much appreciated.